# Did Trump say that laziness is a Black trait?

Tags: donald-trump

Recently CNN interviewed [Jack O'Donnell](https://www.cnn.com/videos/politics/2018/08/14/jack-odonnell-trump-racist-through-and-through-sot-ebof-vpx.cnn) and they talked about a quote from Trump in his (Jack O'Donnell) book.

> I've got black accountants at Trump Castle and at Trump Plaza. Black guys counting my money! I hate it. The only kind of people I want counting my money are short guys that wear yarmulkes every day... I think that the guy is lazy. And it's probably not his fault because laziness is a trait in blacks. It really is. I believe that it's not anything they can control.

Is the any other evidence for this claim?

Comment: [Snopes didn't find any](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/trump-laziness-is-a-trait-in-blacks/), and notes that Trump denies saying it.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) On one hand, we have an author who claims (in that interview) to have taken contemporaraneous notes of a private conversation. On the other, we have Trump denying he said it. What sort of evidence are you looking for that could confirm or refute the claim?

Comment: I'm going to put this on hold, until we get some idea of what an answer could possibly look like, because otherwise it is just looking like a partisan jab.

Comment: @SamHarrington: What do you mean?  Snopes discusses this exact quote (among others) on the page I linked.  They confirm that O'Donnell claims that Trump said it, and then they say that "...neither the statement nor the sentiment behind it has been corroborated elsewhere."

Comment: @NateEldredge Snopes mostly seems to focus on the presentation of that meme (two separate quotes, which they interpreted as being misleadingly placed to make it seem that they belong together). They also note that Trump said: "The stuff O’Donnell wrote about me is probably true" (he changed his mind two years later). I agree with Oddthinking though; in the end, it is the word of one person (+ Trump saying that it's true) against the later word of Trump, and we can't really add any definitive information here as it's from a private meeting.

Comment: @Oddthinking I assure you that this isn't partisan, I am just looking to see if there are other sources then this guy that claim this.

Comment: @NateEldredge Trump routinely denies saying things he said on live TV less than 24 hours prior.